# How to extract data from text files?

Tags: python

So I am having a set of files that I need to extract data from and write in a new txt file, and I am not sure how to do this with Python. Below is a sample data. I am trying to extract the parts from NSF Org, File and Abstract.

Title       : CRB: Genetic Diversity of Endangered Populations of Mysticete Whales:
               Mitochondrial DNA and Historical Demography
Type        : Award
NSF Org     : DEB 
Latest
Amendment
Date        : August 1,  1991
File        : a9000006

Award Number: 9000006
Award Instr.: Continuing grant
Prgm Manager: Scott Collins
          DEB  DIVISION OF ENVIRONMENTAL BIOLOGY
          BIO  DIRECT FOR BIOLOGICAL SCIENCES
Start Date  : June 1,  1990
Expires     : November 30,  1992   (Estimated)
Expected
Total Amt.  : $179720             (Estimated)
Investigator: Stephen R. Palumbi   (Principal Investigator current)
Sponsor     : U of Hawaii Manoa
          2530 Dole Street
          Honolulu, HI  968222225    808/956-7800

NSF Program : 1127      SYSTEMATIC & POPULATION BIOLO
Fld Applictn: 0000099   Other Applications NEC
              61        Life Science Biological
Program Ref : 9285,
Abstract    :

```
          Commercial exploitation over the past two hundred years drove the great    
          Mysticete whales to near extinction.  Variation in the sizes of populations  
          prior to exploitation, minimalpopulation size during exploitation and 
          current population sizes permit analyses of the effects of differing levels 
          of exploitation on species with different biogeographical distributions and 
          life-history characteristics.
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not giving me much to go on but, what I do to read input files from a txt file. This is in Java, hopefully you'll know how to store it in an array of some sort

```
import java.util.Scanner;

import java.io.*;

public class ClockAngles{

public static void main (String [] args) throws IOException {

Scanner reader = null;
String input = "";
try {
    reader = new Scanner (new BufferedReader (new FileReader("FilePath")));

    while (reader.hasNext()) {
        input = reader.next();
        System.out.print(input);

    } 
}

finally {
        if (reader != null) {
        reader.close();
        }
}
```

Python code

```
#!/bin/env python2.7

# Change this to the file with the time input
filename = "filetext"

storeData = []

class Whatever:
def __init__(self, time_str):
    times_list = time_str.split('however you want input to be read')
    self.a = int(times_list[0]) 
    self.b = int(times_list[1]) 
    self.c = int(times_list[2]) 
    # prints the data
    def __str__(self):
    return str(self.a) + " " + str(self.b) + " " + str(self.c)
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I am pretty new, tried to figure out this code but am confused about the  time_list[] lines. Could you please explain? Thanks so much.

Comment: Well this was my code for reading times from a txt file. The time_list is just an array